# React Native iOS Emulator not refreshing upon Hot Reloading or Manual Refresh

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

The title says it all, I can't get my iOS emulator to refresh my React Native app correctly. Either with hot reloading or manual refresh, nothing updates, I have to restart the emulator. How could I troubleshoot this?

Comment: Is your dev server running ?

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I apparently have a problem with Watchman `Error: Watchman error: query failed: synchronization failed: Operation timed out. Make sure watchman is running for this project. See https://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.`

Comment: Ok, I just reinstalled Watchman and the error is gone but my app still doesn't refresh

Comment: What happens when you refresh the app ? does it show error message in terminal where server is running ?

Comment: The emulator says _Hot loading..._ but nothing happens in the Terminal